# Unable to create Equal Gaps between text and div's border

Tags: html, css, text, centering

I'm having 2 divs, inner div and a wrapper div.

**1.** I want that the inner div will always be centered inside the wrapper div.

**2.** I want to always have a Gap/Space of 15 pixels between the text and the inner div's border, on the left side and on the right side.

Please check this image that I made that illustrate the problem:

https://i.ibb.co/Df2gxmF/Divs-Image.jpg

As you can see it shows 3 situations:

**1.** This is OK, I'm getting 15 pixels gaps on left and right.

**2.** This is the problem that I'll like to solve, when the text contains a long word and I play around with the width of the view (the width of the browser) then I'm getting large **unwanted** gap on the right side, between the text and the div's border.

**3.** This is what **I want** to accomplish.

Here is my code in the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/725r9fty

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

.divForText {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="divForText">
    Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... Text... LongWordToTestGapProblem Text... Text...
  </div>
</div>
```

- I want to use pure Html and CSS only, without JavaScript.
- I don't want to break words in the middle.
- Please, if you think that you have a solution try to test it first in the fiddle link that I gave, it takes not more than 20-30 seconds.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Daniel, what you are asking for is currently not possible. By default the text is given sufficient space in order for it to not break word, therefore your "right gap". If you wish to accomplish an aesthetic approach you could break-word (i know i know.. you said it's not what you want) by adding

```
overflow-wrap: break-word;
word-break: break-all;
```

to your `.divForText`.

Also, I would strongly suggest always wrapping your text in any HTML5 tag used for that purpose. Such as `<p>` or any `<h1>, <h2>, <h3>, etc`

Comment: Thanks, but I don't like to see words that are broken into 2 parts in 2 different lines, it doesn't look nice. "By default the text is given sufficient space in order for it to not break word", I didn't understand that. If there is a large gap between the text and the div's border, why can't it just be diminished? Why is it needed?

Answer (score 0):

just need to replace text-align:left with center in css as follows

```
.divForText{
  text-align: center;

}
```

Comment: That's not solving the problem. Yes it's making the gap equal on both sides, but these gaps are much larger than 15 pixels that I asked.